# Resizing Axis in Matplotlib when hiding/showing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, pyqt5

First off, I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow and coding as a whole so please let me know how I can improve my posts in the future. I'm currently working on an application that will read in tabular data (CSV in this case) with variable column counts and ranges, and plot all of the columns into a PyQt5 GUI canvas with embedded matplotlib. The goal is to be able to hide/show individual columns by clicking something to allow quick data comparisons. In my case I've done so by connecting the legend item click events and setting the plots to invisible by reducing the alpha.

Here's a tidbit of the data I'm reading in:

[image]

And my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QStyleOptionComboBox, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import datetime
import sys


def main():

#Read in CSV dataset as Pandas dataframe and set index to column 0
    df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=0)

    #Get the count of columns in the csv file and save the headers as a list
    col_count = len(df.columns)
    col_headers = list(df)


    df['A'] = df['A']*1000

#Form class for displaying the GUI
    class Form(QDialog):

        def __init__(self, parent=None, width=400, height=400):
            super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

            #Create the figure and canvas for the plot
            self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
            self.setWindowTitle("Stock Prices 1990 - 2012")

            #Create Navigation Toolbar (Possibly remove this if adding overhead and no functionality)
            self.navBar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

            #Add Widgets to layout
            layout = QGridLayout()
            layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 2, 0)
            layout.addWidget(self.navBar, 0, 0)

            #Apply layout settings
            self.setLayout(layout)

            #Connect the pick event on the canvas to the onpick method
            self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

            # Add the dict as a class method so it can be passed
            self.lined = dict()

        def plot(self):
            #Create Plots and set axis labels
            plt.cla()
            ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            ax.set_xlabel('Date')
            ax.set_ylabel('Price')

            #Empty list to hold the tuples of lines plotted
            lines = []

            #Set variables for each column in pandas dataframe
            for i in range(col_count):
                x, = ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(df.index), df[col_headers[i]], label=col_headers[i])
                lines.append(x)

            # Create legend from label properties
            leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
            leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)

            for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
                legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
                self.lined[legline] = origline

            ax.autoscale(True, axis='y')

            #Draw canvas
            self.canvas.draw()

        def onpick(self, event):
            # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
            # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
            legline = event.artist
            origline = self.lined[legline]
            vis = not origline.get_visible()
            origline.set_visible(vis)
            # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
            # have been toggled
            if vis:
                legline.set_alpha(1.0)
            else:
                legline.set_alpha(0.2)

            self.canvas.draw()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    form.plot()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A picture of the graph working:

[image]

That part is all working wonderfully. Now the issue is that I would like the plot to re-scale to fit whatever is currently visible. For example, if my column (y-axis) contains data in the range of 10,000 - 11,000 and I hide that axis and show a plot with ranges 10-20, I would like the Y-axis to rescale to fit the currently displayed dataset. So ideally, when I click the legend I would like to see the graph attempt to fit the current dataset. Obviously side-by-side comparisons of datasets in drastically different ranges will still not work but I'd like to be able to view similar dataranges in the same plot and have it automatically switch when I change to a dataset with a different range. I've attempted to enable autoscaling but I'm guessing because I'm merely reducing the alpha to invisible, it is not rescaling because the plots are still active. I'm not sure if I should look for a way to actually remove the plot and redraw the canvas, or perhaps a way to incorporate scaling into my current method for hiding/showing the columns. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As to what to improve in your question: Don't spend only half a sentence on the actual problem. *"I would like the plot to re-scale to fit whatever is currently visible"* is not enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Good note; thank you. Not sure how I didn't see that on the review before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update the limits of the axes one may use

```
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
```

However, you are entirely correct: As long as a line is in the axes, whether visible or not, the axes limits will not change.
A solution may be to remove the line in question from the axes (`line.remove()`) and add it again upon click on the legend (`ax.add_line(line)`). In this case one may still use the line's visibility as a flag on whether the line in question should be added or removed on the event of a click.

A complete example, based on the [matplotlib legend picker](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html) code (as the QT part from the question seems irrelavant here).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.5)
y1 = 2*np.sin(np.pi*t)
y2 = 4*np.sin(np.pi*2*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
line1, = ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, color='red', label='1 HZ')
line2, = ax.plot(t, y2, lw=2, color='blue', label='2 HZ')
leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)

lines = [line1, line2]
lined = dict()
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(5)  
    lined[legline] = origline


def onpick(event):
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]

    vis = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(vis)

    # if line is made invisible, also remove it from axes
    # if line is made visible again, add it to axes again
    if not vis:
        origline.remove()
    else:
        ax.add_line(origline)
    # in any case relimit the axes
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()

    if vis:
        legline.set_alpha(1.0)
    else:
        legline.set_alpha(0.2)

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```